# Java Swing's GridBagLayout will not position component at the top of the grid cell

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I have tried to boil this down as far as I can in code. I have been using GridBagLayout for a long time and for some reason I have never run into this situation.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setResizeable(true);

JPanel guiHolder = new JPanel();
guiHolder.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
guiHolder.add(new JLabel("my test"), gbc);

dialog.add(guiHolder);
dialog.setSize(new Dimension(320, 240);
dialog.setSize(true);
```

The JLabel ends up square in the center of the screen. How can I get it to go to the top? I have looked at [How To Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). I am stumped...

Comment: I'd take a look at the layout manager of the dialog.

Comment: The posted code doesnt' even compile. Post a proper `SSCCE` if you want help.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to fat finger in my code. I fixed one flaw. Hopefully it compiles now.

Comment: `Hopefully it compiles now.` hopefully is not good enough. Try it yourself. Where is the main method? We are not here to debug your code and make it compile. If you want halp, make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Works for me. After I fixed your compile errors and placed your code in a runnable demo, the label appears centered at the top of the dialog (as it should with PAGE_START).

Comment: Ughhh this is embarrassing, I missed adding in the line for gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH. When I comment that out or change it to NONE it works!

Comment: -1, And that is exactly why you post a proper SSCCE. That line of code doesn't even exist in the code you posted. So we wasted time looking at code that you didn't even test.

Comment: @user1202394 : No, fill was not needed to get the desired results. You needed to fix the still remaining errors and it would work as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you fixed your compile errors and wrapped your code into a runnable demo, you'd see that GridBagLayout works as advertised:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test implements Runnable
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Test());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setResizable(true);  // fixed mispelling here

    JPanel guiHolder = new JPanel();
    guiHolder.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    guiHolder.add(new JLabel("my test"), gbc);

    dialog.add(guiHolder);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
    dialog.setVisible(true);  // fixed wrong method name here
  }
}
```

Comment: -1, it is the OP's responsibility to post a proper SSCCE. We should not be doing the work for them.

Comment: @camickr Usually I would agree, but in this case the OP presented a bogus solution in a comment, so I posted this for future visitors who may be experiencing difficulties with GBL and may find this post looking for answers.

Comment: Wow, so many haters in the house. My development box has no internet connection, so I typed my SSCCE in. There is nothing wrong with helping out the OP. I will be more conscientious next time. Calling my solution bogus is over-reacting. I am suffocating under all the snobbery in the air.

Comment: @user1202394 No snobbery on my part anyway. Your solution was not a proper one. You'll see that if you later have to add more content.  Perhaps "incorrect" or "misleading" would be more appropriate.